# How do you extend a C# interface in C++/CLR?

Tags: c++-cli, clr

I'm really frustrated with this one.  I'm trying to extend a C# created interface in C++/CLR.  The interface has one method and I've declared it in my class, but the compiler keeps telling me that I must still provide an implementation for the interface method.  What more can I do?  What am I missing!?

Does anyone have any examples of how to extend a C# interface in CLR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out!  I needed to make the implementation of elements virtual.  I hope this helps other people with this same issue.